# Input path does not exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ubuntu

I am new to spark. 
I'm trying to run my first word count program. But I cannot get it to start 
I typed in:

```
scala> val input = sc.textFile("/home/amel/word.txt").collect()
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not 
exist: file:/home/amel/word.txt
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:204)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:253)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:253)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:945)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
  ... 49 elided
```

Please help.

Comment: Maybe try: `/home/amel/word.txt` - also confirm that the txt file exists in that directory

Comment: I've tried moving the text file to home just to make the path easier...it wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you try with `file` protocol? So it would be `file:///home/amel/word.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory, so it is *probably* something simple that you are missing. Can you modify your script and run it as shown below.

Please modify the "fileName" value to where you think the file is.

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import sys.process._

/************ Modify this line with your data's file name **************/
val fileName = "/home/gmc/exists.csv"

if (Files.exists(Paths.get(fileName))) {
  sc.textFile(fileName).take(5).foreach(println)
} else {
  s"ls -l ${Paths.get(fileName).getParent}".!
}
```

If you run it with a file that exists, it will display some of the content of that file. If the file does not exist, it will give a directory listing of the parent.

Hopefully this will help you work out what the problem is. If you can not work out the solution using the above, please add the **entire** output from the above script into your original question.